# Closure in $<P([0,1)),\{\bigcup, \bigcap\}> $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to define the closre of the sub set $M:=\{[a,b):0\leq a\leq b<1\}$ in the algebra $<P([0,1)),\{\bigcup, \bigcap\}>$.

Where do I start? I can think only of specific examples to elements that belong or not belong to $Cl(M)$ but I don't know how to generalize my specific examples.

Comment: Start by describing the unions and intersections of 2. Then bring in a 3rd. Then a 4th. Do you see a pattern? If the answer isn't clear -- experiment.

Comment: $ \{[a'_1,a'_2)\cup ... \cup [a'_n, a''_n):  n\  is\ natural\ number \wedge 0\leq a'_1 <a''_1 <...<a'_n<a''_n\} $

Comment: The key is to look at various *cases* -- what happens when you form unions or intersections of disjoint intervals? Intervals which overlap? Intervals in which one is contained in the other?

Comment: I always get an empty set or a union of finite number of intervals from this form: $[a,b) \cup ... \cup [y,z) $

Comment: Then -- prove that you are correct. You should stipulate whether or not you are assuming that the subintervals in the expression are disjoint. Both are equivalent ways of describing the same family of subsets, but one is more elegant than the other.

Comment: How is closure defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to prove that $Cl(M) = \{\emptyset\}\cup \{[a'_1,a''_1)\cup ... \cup [a'_n, a''_n) : n\in \omega, 0\leq a_1'< a_1''< a'_2<...< a_n''<1\} $ by proving that each set is a subset of the other set.